# Edit hyperlink validation

Tags: validation, sharepoint-online

Is there any possibility to add another protocol to the hyperlink-type in sharepoint?

I want to add a notes (notes://***) to the top level navigation-bar.

Is there something I can extend or where I can edit the validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SharePoint navigation Hyperlinks must begin with http://,https://,mailto:,ftp://,file://,/,# or \.

If you want to use the "notes://***", as a workaround, you can add the link using jQuery code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
     $(".ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox>ul>li>ul").append("<li class='static'><a href='notes://xxx'>MyNote</a></li>");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, and how can I add this? In an own webpart which I have to deploy and add to my site?

Comment: Classic site, we can add code into master page, modern site, we can use SPFX Extension.https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-add-a-js-file-to-all-pages-in-a-spfx-modern-pages-using-sharepoint-framework-extension/

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not possible to turn off easily the OOB link validation without any customization. Depends on the output You need maybe You could use a note column and in edit HTML content of the filed just put the link tag manually like:

```
<a href="note://someLink">someLink</a>
```

. After save SharePoint will render it as link on list webpart.